# How do I make an MVC ActionLink call a POST method?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, actionlink

I have an HTML.ActionLink that is acting perfectly except it is not hitting the POST method.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Join Now!", "JoinFleet", "Members", new { ID =Model.ID , fleet = 1 }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
```

it results with the following URL as expected.

`http://localhost:64096/Members/JoinFleet/2403?fleet=1`

I need it to work exactly like this but, hit my POST `JoinFleet` method.

I toyed with a few ways I could accomplish this task. I was also trying to pass the value of a checked radiobutton to a using as a param.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("JoinFleet", "Members", new { fleet = 3 },
FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-group" }))
```

and then submit with a standard submit button
I would be very happy with either making that Action hit my post method in my controller or passing the value of the radio button as the param value for fleet in my using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating a link to a controller action in ASP.NET MVC, using the generic ActionLink method is preferable, because it allows for strongly typed links that are refactoring friendly.

Default: ActionLink

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.ID })
```

Using Button:

```
<input type="button" title="Delete" value="D" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Delete", "movies", new { id = item.ID })'" />
```

Using Image:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Delete", "movies", new { id = item.ID })" title="Edit">
<img src="../../Content/Images/Delete.png" />
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am familiar with the ActionLink. My question is, how do I get this one to target my post method of the same name.

Comment: I need this: @Html.ActionLink("Join Now!", "JoinFleet", "Members", new { ID = Model.ID , fleet = 1 }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })  to hit my post method JoinFleet

Comment: You can't use an ActionLink because that just renders an anchor <a> tag. But you could use an Ajax.ActionLink(), that allow; s you to specify a HTTP Method which you could set to "POST".  Such as: `@Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.ApkModelId }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST" })`

Comment: Here is  Clear guide you may check: https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Submit-Post-Form-using-ActionLink-in-ASPNet-MVC.aspx

Comment: This is what I came up with. @Ajax.ActionLink("Join Now!", "JoinFleet", "Members", new { ID = Model.ID, fleet = 1 }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST" }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })

Comment: I still do not seem to be hitting the post method. I have never used AJAX before. Do I need some js or something to make this work?

Comment: This is what it had in the link you sent me:     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#submit").click(function () {
                document.forms[0].submit();
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>

Comment: Install Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax and reference jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js file in the bundle or page for Ajax.ActionLink to work, otherwise clicking it will show - Error 404: Page not found.